# UILabel not working with NSAttributedString + NSParagraphStyle for Right-To-Left

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, right-to-left, nsparagraphstyle

I'm having problems with UILabels that use `NSAttributedStrings` with `NSParagraphStyle` when I use `UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft`.

I have a demo app with just 2 labels on the UI.

They have leading and trailing constraints.

[image: The two labels]

I'm making the app Right to Left in the AppDelegate with

```
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

And I'm just configuring the labels with the following code

```
let labelAText = "Foo"

let mutAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: labelAText)
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .natural
paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = .natural

mutAttrString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle.copy()], range: NSMakeRange(0, labelAText.count))

labelA.attributedText = mutAttrString
labelB.text = "Bar"
```

Which results in this:

[[image: wrong label[2]]

The `labelB (Bar)` is working as expected, but the `labelA (Foo)` isn't. And if I just remove the `NSParagraphStyle` it starts working. Mind that I'm not even changing anything on it, but just by using it it's messing up with the alignment.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

Comment: try using `paragraphStyle.alignment = .natural`

Comment: @MilanNosáľ that's the default alignment, but I've already tried it. No luck.

Comment: Maybe with adding `NSWritingDirectionAttributeName`?

Comment: I don't want to force the paragraph to be RightToLeft, I have it with `natural` so it can decide considering the direction set on the appearance.

Comment: An update may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326178/uilabel-not-working-with-nsattributedstring-nsparagraphstyle-for-right-to-left/48326364#48326364

Answer (score 2):

[NSMutableParagraphStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmutableparagraphstyle) has a property [baseWritingDirection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1534601-basewritingdirection) (enum [NSWritingDirection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nswritingdirection)). Set it to [rightToLeft](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nswritingdirection/1534029-righttoleft)

Try this

```
paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = NSWritingDirection.rightToLeft
```

**Edit**:(May this help you)

> If the value of property (baseWritingDirection) is NSWritingDirectionNaturalDirection, the receiver resolves the writing direction to either NSWritingDirectionLeftToRight or NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft, depending on the direction for the user’s language preference setting.

```
class func defaultWritingDirection(forLanguage languageName: String?) -> NSWritingDirection
```

**languageName**: The language specified in ISO language region format. Can be nil to return a default writing direction derived from the user’s defaults database.

Solution using languageName = "ar"

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelA: UILabel!

let labelAText = "Foo"
let mutAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Foo")
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
//paragraphStyle.alignment = .natural
paragraphStyle.baseWritingDirection = NSParagraphStyle.defaultWritingDirection(forLanguage: "ar")
mutAttrString.setAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle], range: NSMakeRange(0, labelAText.count))

labelA.attributedText = mutAttrString
```

Here is list of languages: [Codes for the Representation of Names of Languages](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php)

**Note: Use `ISO 639-1` code for language. Direction of label text depends upon natural direction of language.**

Here is result:

[image]

This Apple document will help you - [Supporting Right-to-Left Languages](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, but I don't want to force the rightToLeft direction, I wanted it to determine it by itself, like the other label does it. I'm using `natural`.

Comment: @miguel.gazela I agree with your concern. You are absolutely right. Code should be dynamic (without force update). May `defaultWritingDirection` help you.

Comment: Yeah, it works like that, and it's definitely one way of solving it. But the original problem remains. Why isn't the alignment and baseWritingDirection set as natural enough to make it flip like an ordinary text label? That's what I would like to know. But thanks!

Comment: @miguel.gazela There is an answer to your question: `If you the value of this property is NSWritingDirectionNaturalDirection, the receiver resolves the writing direction to either NSWritingDirectionLeftToRight or NSWritingDirectionRightToLeft, depending on the direction for the user’s language preference setting.`  What is natural language for your label? It should be English (en) right? So it follows direction of language english.

Comment: no, I've changed the device language to Arabic, I've used Arabic strings, and it still displays the `labelA` on the left of the screen.